# How to make a Horizontal Select List in React Native, any best package for this?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, react-native

I have been developing an mobile application in react native. There is a need of Horizontal Select List in a screen ( Sorry , i couldn't find the name of the component).

Design of the Page :

[image]

In the Image, after price , the Unit and Time Slot has a select box like user can select only one box with this design horizontally. How to achieve this.

I dont have any idea how to achieve this, please guide me if there is any package for this, or is there any way that i can achieve this ?

**Update:** I have achieved the layout using FlatList in react native. Now how to achive the single selection function.This is my Flatlist

```
<FlatList
                        horizontal={true}
                        data={this.qtyList}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => (
                                <TouchableHighlight 
                                onPress={() => {
                                    this.props.qtyListSelector(item.id)
                                }}
                                >
                                <Card
                                containerStyle={{  borderRadius: 5 }}
                                >
                                <Text>
                                {item.qty}
                                </Text>
                                </Card>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        )}
                    />
```

I am using Redux to grab the value of the touched card. Now i need to change color and highlight the user selected card Like the above example image. I think it can be done using component level state. Please guide as, couldnt figure out the steps as i am begginer

Answer (score 0):

You can use FlatList with horizontal true.

```
<FlatList horizontal={true}/>
```

And also in this link, you can find horizontal FlatList usage. That can give you start point.

https://streetsmartdev.com/create-horizontal-list-react-native/

Comment: if so , how to select and highlight a single item which user selects ? is it possible with flatlist ?

Comment: For example each FlatList item can be wrapped by a TouchableOpacity and you can do  what you need in the onPress of TouchableOpacity. You can give a highligt with style. Also if you want, you can use a package something like that react-native-snap-carousel or another. It can handle all of you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the horizontal Flatlist solution doesn't work for you, I've had good experiences using https://www.npmjs.com/package/swiper.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without any external library, or you can use react native swiper, but that library has some issues when it comes to select.
The approach you can use without any library is

```
state = {
   data: [
     { key: '1', name: 'mark', selected: false },
     { key: '2', name: 'john', selected: false }
   ],
   selectedItem: null
}
```

...

```
<FlatList 
   horizontal={true}
   data={this.state.data} 
   extraData={this.state.selectedItem}
   renderItem={this.renderItem}
/>
```

You need extraData to make sure your `FlatList`, re-renders when you press on the individual item.
Now inside your renderItem Method, You can simple use something like,

```
renderItem =({item, index}) => {

  return (
  <TouchableOpacity 
   onPress={() => {
   // I wrote it like this so you could understand.
   // first get your previous array
   const tempArray = this.state.data;
   // If you want single selection, add the code I wrote in the end 
   here.
   // second change the selected value of this item
   tempArray[index].selected = true;
   // update the state
   this.setState({ data: tempArray, selectedItem: item });
   // here selected Item is not used, but you might need it in future purpose.
}}
   style={{ backgroundColor: item.selected ? 'orange' : 'white' }}>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
}
```

This approach will select multiple items...If you want to unselect previous.
then you need to map over the previous array or use the selectedItem state to find the element with the help of `findIndex` method for arrays.(you need to implement it inside onPress)
for map, a simple example would be

`const tempArray = tempArray.map((singleItem) => {...singleItem, selected: false }) );`

**NOTE: I wrote this code here only, So it might have some mistakes. Please do let me know if any.**

Comment: I copy pasted as you said, but nothing happens. Couldn't figure the error also as there is not error ! ( sorry totally a beginner )

Comment: It should work, make sure you are doing everything right, and if possible do post your code

Comment: I have achieved the look using flatlist and horizontal property. But , how to implement the selection procedure. As, I need to make user to select one option from the given.

Comment: I have also added the code to achieve that functionality,

Comment: Can we chat ? Actually couldnt understand the code brother !